# My screen turned off when I left my laptop unattended, and now it won't turn back on

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, laptop, xinit

I went to have breakfast while my laptop was running an Xorg session, now the screen doesn't turn on no matter what I do. I tried switching ttys, no dice. I ran a program using `startx`, my distro is Arch.
I don't want to reboot it. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try SSHing into the laptop and killing xorg that way? For example through your phone or another computer.
When I had to do that last time I had to do `pkill <window manager>`

Comment: 1) is it possible with arch linux to change to a terminal via Ctrl-Alt-F1? If yes, did you try it and did it work? (you did and wrote it, didn't realize on first reading ...)
2) see Lavacats solution - remote ssh login if both things don't work, to possibly avoid this in future
* is your swap partition big enough to take the content of your RAM? I had exactly the same problem with my laptop going to sleep and not waking up anymore, because my swap partition was to small - extending the partition eliminated this (opensuse 15.2 or 15.3)

Comment: @Lavacast, sorry to get back to you so late but it happened again, and as if in spite it disconnected from my Wi-Fi hotspot too. I managed connect via Bluetooth. So I guess the only way is SSH over Bluetooth. Would you have any idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Also forget to mention, I only have a phone available at this time.